Order update packet in shopware 6 admin api
In my shopware admin store i have created an order with quantity of 1
I was trying to updated it through postman by updating quantity of 2 for lineitem.
please any one faced this below error while updating the order and it will be really appreciated if any suggestions
Method: POST -> shopware_storeurl/api/order/{id}
Below is my requesting body packet :
{
    "id": "018e65c2d6d571ac8ddd92548a6f2a67",
    "orderNumber": "10113",
    "billingAddressId": "018e65c2d6d473d1964a17bbcf19fa76",
    "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca",
    "languageId": "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b",
    "salesChannelId": "a998231fe4d94f3da04f19c84222d108",
    "orderDateTime": "2024-03-22T10:44:11.601+00:00",
    "stateId": "6343591dec0343b3a34ce5f7204c4219",
    "price": {
        "extensions": [],
        "netPrice": 8.4000000000000004,
        "totalPrice": 10.0,
        "calculatedTaxes": [
            {
                "extensions": [],
                "tax": 1.6000000000000001,
                "taxRate": 19.0,
                "price": 10.0
            }
        ],
        "taxRules": [
            {
                "extensions": [],
                "taxRate": 19.0,
                "percentage": 100.0
            }
        ],
        "positionPrice": 10.0,
        "taxStatus": "gross",
        "rawTotal": 10.0
    },
    "shippingCosts": {
        "extensions": [],
        "unitPrice": 0.0,
        "quantity": 1,
        "totalPrice": 0.0,
        "calculatedTaxes": [
            {
                "extensions": [],
                "tax": 0.0,
                "taxRate": 19.0,
                "price": 0.0
            }
        ],
        "taxRules": [
            {
                "extensions": [],
                "taxRate": 19.0,
                "percentage": 100.0
            }
        ],
        "referencePrice": null,
        "listPrice": null,
        "regulationPrice": null
    },
    "currencyFactor": 1.0,
    "lineItems": [
        {
            "id": "018e65c2d6d372e6835c81cd065eef9d",
            "orderId": "018e65c2d6d571ac8ddd92548a6f2a67",
            "identifier": "018e65abd3aa718489a8555f609ac849",
            "quantity": 2,
            "label": "Linux RedHat V1",
            "position": 1,
            "states": [
                "is-physical"
            ],
            "price": {
                "unitPrice": 10.0,
                "quantity": 1,
                "totalPrice": 10.0,
                "calculatedTaxes": [
                    {
                        "extensions": [],
                        "tax": 1.6000000000000001,
                        "taxRate": 19.0,
                        "price": 10.0
                    }
                ],
                "taxRules": [
                    {
                        "extensions": [],
                        "taxRate": 19.0,
                        "percentage": 100.0
                    }
                ],
                "referencePrice": null,
                "listPrice": null,
                "regulationPrice": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "stateMachineState": {
        "id": "6343591dec0343b3a34ce5f7204c4219",
        "technicalName": "open",
        "name": "Offen",
        "stateMachineId": "80a9673b0435413fbac1b1612eb1db57"
    }
}

Bellow Error I'm getting :
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "FRAMEWORK__WRITE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION",
            "status": "400",
            "detail": "Changing the state-machine-state of this entity is not allowed for scope crud. Either change the state-machine-state via a state-transition or use a different scope.",
            "template": "Changing the state-machine-state of this entity is not allowed for scope {{ scope }}. Either change the state-machine-state via a state-transition or use a different scope.",
            "meta": {
                "parameters": {
                    "{{ scope }}": "crud"
                }
            },
            "source": {
                "pointer": "/0/stateId"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I have tried with the bellow shopware api document guide
https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/3cc867261ff28-partially-update-information-about-a-order-resource

Possibly related question: Add existing product to order with shopware 6 api
